# Counterexample of convergence in distribution at points of discontinuity

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

We define convergence in distribution where $F$ is continuous. To illustrate the importance of continuity in the definition, an example was given in the class which I did not understand. Consider a sequence of points $x_n\uparrow x_0$ and point mass prob measures $\delta_n$ at $x_n$. So he said $F_n(x_n)\not\to F(x_0)$ but as I see it $\{F_n(x_n)\}$ is a sequence of step functions that does converge to another step function? A hint is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect he meant to say $F_n(x_0) \not\to F(x_0)$.  Observe that $F_n(x_0) = 1$ for every $n$ but $F(x_0) = 0$.

However, as you say, intuitively we really want for $F_n$ to "converge" to $F$.  So asking for $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ for every $x$ is too strong, and thus we weaken the definition by only requiring it to hold at points $x$ where $F$ is continuous.  This definition turns out to be a better fit for what we are trying to describe.